# Regex to match a whole string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following list of produtcs (in a .txt file) :

```
#ART#NC3FX;price1
#ART#NC3FX;price2
#ART#NC3FX;price3
#ART#NC3FXX;price1
#ART#NC3FXX;price2
#ART#NC3FXX;price3
#ART#NC3FXX;price1
#ART#NC3FXX;price2
#ART#NC3FXX;price3
#ART#NC3FX-HD;price1
#ART#NC3FX-HD;price2
#ART#NC3FX-HD;price3
```

I'd like to get all the occurrences of the first one (**ART#NC3FX**).

Using this regular expression

```
@"(^|\b)#ART#NC3FX(\b|$)";
```

I retrieve the first three lines, which is fine, but I also get the lines for the reference **#ART#NC3FX-HD**.

What should I do to prevent this from happening ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is there a reason to not parse these values into a data structure?

Comment: All these values are not parsed yet when I'm performing this (the file is acutally more complex), so I have to find a way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex finds a match because the `-` hyphen is not a word character, and you tell the regex engine (with `\b`) that the character after `D` should be a non-word character. So, you get a match.

You may use a negative lookahead:

```
@"\B#ART#NC3FX(?![\w-])"
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP2lU6/1)

The `\B` will match a position at the beginning of the string or a non-word boundary, and `(?![\w-])` lookahead will fail a match if the string is followed with a word character or a hyphen. If you test independent strings replace `\B` with `^` (start of string).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works like a charm. I would upvote your answer if I could !

Comment: @stribizhev so you upvote op in-order to get upvote from him.. :(

Comment: Avinash, I would upvote anyway. This is a question showing effort and I often upvote such questions. I often upvote questions.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if i understand your answer correctly, but why dont you look for the first ; like:

```
@"^#ART#NC3FX(;|$)"
```

EDIT: See Avinash's Answer

Comment: This is Avinash's first suggestion.